# Swift- function with parameters from a button

Tags: swift, function, swift2, nsmenuitem

My function is "openWindow" and takes an int. I can run the function with parameters without any problems.

`openWindow(2)`

and this works

`let OpenView : NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "OpenWindow", action: #selector(openWindow), keyEquivalent: "")`

But this doesn't work.

`let OpenView : NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "OpenWindow", action: #selector(openWindow(2)), keyEquivalent: "")`

Comment: Read the duplicate, but in your particular case (if you really want to pass "2"), you'll probably want to investigate the `tag` property, which lets you attach an integer to your `NSMenuItem`.

Comment: yes using tags did the trick.